# Get users First Letter of First Name in Flutter with Firebase?

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database

I have got the user's first name fine, but I'm wondering how I can create an icon using the user's first letter in their name. See attached the UI.

See code below.

[User Profile UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5apBu.png)

**User Profile Page Screen**

```
BlocBuilder(
    cubit: BlocProvider.of<UserBloc>(context),
    builder: (context, User user) {
      return Text(
        (user == null || user.firstName == null)
            ? 'Welcome'
            : '${user.firstName}',
        style: TextStyle(
          fontFamily: 'Helvetica Neue',
          fontSize: 25,
          color: const Color(0xff3a4759),
        ),
        textAlign: TextAlign.left,
      );
    }),
```

Please note "UserBloc" is not relevant to the question so I haven't included it in this post.

Comment: Updated to add my code

Comment: Okay, I have updated the psot

Comment: Cleaning up comments, since the problems are now addressed in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below code for a Stateless widget will create an Icon according to the UI you showed for reference.

It takes in the parameters:

`firstName` - The name of the person as `String`.

`backgroundColor`- The background colour for the circle enclosing the first letter.

`textColor`- The colour for the first letter

```
class NameIcon extends StatelessWidget {
  final String firstName;
  final Color backgroundColor;
  final Color textColor;

  const NameIcon(
      {Key key, @required this.firstName, this.backgroundColor= Colors.white, this.textColor= Colors.black,})
      : super(key: key);

  String get firstLetter => this.firstName.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FittedBox(
      fit: BoxFit.contain,
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      child: Container(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          shape: BoxShape.circle,
          color: this.backgroundColor,
          border: Border.all(color: Colors.black, width: 0.5),
        ),
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: Text(this.firstLetter, style: TextStyle(color: this.textColor)),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The widget will automatically fit the size and height of the parent widget or a Container, if you want to specify the values explicitly then remove the `FittedBox` widget and then specify the height and width of the container.

OutPut:

[image]

---

Whole Code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String title;
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.amber,
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          height: 150.0,
          width: 300.0,
          child: NameIcon(
            firstName: 'Hello',
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class NameIcon extends StatelessWidget {
  final String firstName;
  final Color backgroundColor;
  final Color textColor;
      const NameIcon(
          {Key key, @required this.firstName, this.backgroundColor= Colors.white, this.textColor= Colors.black,})
      : super(key: key);

  String get firstLetter => this.firstName.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FittedBox(
      fit: BoxFit.contain,
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      child: Container(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          shape: BoxShape.circle,
          color: this.backgroundColor,
          border: Border.all(color: Colors.black, width: 0.5),
        ),
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: Text(this.firstLetter, style: TextStyle(color: this.textColor)),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You can also just do a simple **firstName[0].toUpperCase()** to get the first letter. Just be sure to check, that the string's length is actually more or equal to 1.

Comment: Thank you! This worked, here was my final code for the icon

Answer (score 1):

```
FittedBox(
  fit: BoxFit.contain,
  alignment: Alignment.center,
  child: Container(
    alignment: Alignment.center,
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      shape: BoxShape.circle,
      color: Colors.yellow,
      border: Border.all(color: Colors.black, width: 0.5),
    ),
    padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
    child: BlocBuilder(
                          cubit: BlocProvider.of<UserBloc>(context),
                          builder: (context, User user) {
                            return Text(
                              (user == null || user.firstName == null)
                                  ? 'Welcome'
                                  : '${user.firstName[0].toUpperCase()}',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontFamily: 'Helvetica Neue',
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                fontSize: 25,
                                color: const Color(0xff3a4759),
                              ),
                              textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                            );
                          }),
  ),
),
```